# Multisite, can't see sub blogs

Tags: multisite, htaccess

Based on advice I got from another [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168446), I created a development copy of a multisite installation I've inherited inside of a [Vagrant VM](http://vagrantup.com).

On a test site as described here...

[image]

I get an error

[image]

Could it be something in the .htaccess file?

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Are you sure that htaccess files are allowed on your server?  Check that first.  The 404 is coming from your http server and not making it to WP.

Comment: Hi @user42826, how's about you moving that down to the answer section so I can mark it correct? In other words, thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 404 is coming from your http server and not making it to WP.  htaccess is not configured on your server.

Answer (score 2):

**Assumption:** you're running on an **Apache** web server. If not, you'll have to translate the relevant portions of this answer into the **nginx** or **IIS** or whatever server-ese.

---

Per [the Codex page on setting up Multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network), you should have **Pretty Permalinks** enabled and working on your site *prior* to setting up Multisite. (See *Step 1*.) Pretty Permalinks require you to set up rewrite rules in a `.htaccess` file (or else in your server's config file).

Proper `.htaccess` files (as mentioned by @user42826 in his/her answer) depend on the version of WordPress you're starting from. Since the current version is 4.0, I'm going to assume that's what you're dealing with.

`.htaccess` file for WP Multisite > 3.5:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

If you're using a version older than 3.5 (and if you are, please upgrade), then check out [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration#.htaccess_and_Mod_Rewrite) for alternate `.htacess` rules.

**Edit** -- it looks like you've got the `.htaccess` rules for versions lower than 3.5 (ie, 3.4.2 or earlier). If you've *upgraded* your WordPress Multisite installation from 3.4.2 or earlier to 4.0, that should work. If you've been running WordPress single-site since before 3.4.2, you should read this:

> You *cannot choose **Sub-directory** Install* (for a path-based network) if your existing WordPress installation has been set up for more than a month, due to issues with existing permalinks.

From the [*Restrictions*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network#Restrictions) section on the **Before You Create a Network** page.