# Missing images after moving servers

Tags: multisite, images, htaccess

I cloned an inherited WP Multisite and have got it up and running thanks to advice in a  [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168446) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/168798) previous questions. Things are moving along with the exception of images.

**Missing Images**

On one of the sub-blogs, images *inside* content posts aren't showing up. For example I have `<img title="CNDP Pic" src="http://192.168.33.10/study/files/2012/06/C123-Pic.png" alt="Pic" width="150" height="108">`. However, the browser cannot find this file.

[image]

**Found in the file system**

However, I do see this file on the file system. 

`vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/var/www$ find | grep C123-Pic.png
./wp-content/blogs.dir/18/files/2012/06/C123-Pic.png`

**Database looks okay**
[image]

**htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

**How to remap?**
Is there an area in the database where I can correct this mapping `/study/files/2012/06/ = /wp-content/blogs.dir/18/files/2012/06/`)?

Comment: Just run a full find and replace on this database.  [This](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) is a good tool.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out .htaccess was missing the following lines

```
# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Still... why would you want to rewrite this for EVERY REQUEST when you also could do a database replacement?

Comment: Well this is an inherited project. I need to create a dev space to test updates and get this back to where it needs to be. I will consider this however! Thank you

Comment: Besides if the multisite setup was started before WP 3.5 the rule is [supposed to be there](http://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration#.htaccess_and_Mod_Rewrite). @edelwater